# Entity framework .ToList() is slow? (Query all)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

```
public List<Employee> GetEmployees(){
     var employee = new ApplicationDBContext().Employee;

     return employee.ToList();
}

//somewhere in other part of code.
//Use GetEmployees.
var employees = GetEmployees();
var importantEmployees = employees.Where(e => e.IsImportant == true);
```

In terms of performance, this method is feasible?
Is there any solution to make it fast?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As soon as `GetEmployees()` executes `ToList()`, you retrieve *all* the records from the database, not just the "important" ones. By the time you execute the `Where` clause later on, it's too late.

Create another method, where you filter with `Where` before calling `ToList()`.

```
public List<Employee> GetImportantEmployees()
{
    var employee = new ApplicationDBContext().Employee;

    return employee.Where(e => e.IsImportant).ToList();
}
```

Other than that, I'm not sure what else you can do to make it faster from your C# code. Apply more filters if you only need a subset of the "important" employees (also before calling `ToList()`).